# Use a file as STDIO in PHP

Tags: php, stdin

I am using a PHP script which input lines from user using STDIN. All the lines basically contains string values. So, instead of inputting them each time manually I wish the PHP to use a file as a STDIN such that when the code input a line from STDIN, it will automatically get line from a file one at a time. How, can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the parameters when using PHP CLI?

Comment: Maybe `php -f file.php < input.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a file’s content to a program’s STDIN, either via a pipe:

```
cat file.txt | php -f script.php
```

Or via redirection:

```
php -f script.php < file.txt
```